# how to debug python module with VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Im trying to watch variables in a module I am building using VSCode.
I tried adding two configurations on the launch.json: module and current file. But neither does precisely what I'm trying to do. In my workflow I have a module that I install with pip install, and when Im extending it, I write small functions that call the module; which when module is working I turn into tests for pytest.

I would like to have a debug configuration that allows me to start the module from these external scripts, while at the same time putting breakpoints and watch variables inside the module. Neither of the configurations below help do that. Has anyone experience in this? Thank you

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Module",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "mymodule"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use debug option in run menu. You can use the F5 shortcut too for starting to debug.

About your problem, I suggest you to change the `launch.json` file firstly. This file manages your debugging procedure but you need also to read working with breakpoints.
The below reference is very perfect to start.

[Python Development in Visual Studio Code](https://realpython.com/python-development-visual-studio-code/)

[launch.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t04bC.jpg) is my `launch.json` file which causes to code run according to relative path.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @ali, but this doesnt do what i need. I get what a breakpoint is; I used them in Visual Studio and C++. In VScode,  running the "Python Current File" config, I can trigger breakpoints on the file, but not those inside the module called. eg. if my file does `import mymodule; mymodule.dosomething()` and I have a breakpoint  inside dosomething(), it isnt triggered, regardless if I put the break in the code in ~/dev/mymodule or in the pip installed code in my ~/miniconda3/.../mymodule. Maybe this happens because the installed code is built, so I should be somehow linking symbols?